# Can not import theano after installation windows 10

Tags: python, anaconda, theano

I've still not been able to resolve this problem, after working on it for a week. 
I'm thinking of giving up and just running theano on a virutal machine; there just doesn't seem to be any support out there for Windows 10! 
Or am I wrong; is there an easy fix to this?

```
>>> import theano
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 75, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 92, in <module>
    raise ImportError()
ImportError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1784, in _try_compile_tmp
    os.remove(exe_path + ".exe")
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\cturn\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\try_march_3v6ffkv9.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
    from theano.compile import (
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from theano.compile.function_module import *
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 21, in <module>
    import theano.compile.mode
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\compile\mode.py", line 10, in <module>
    import theano.gof.vm
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\vm.py", line 659, in <module>
    from . import lazylinker_c
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 125, in <module>
    args = cmodule.GCC_compiler.compile_args()
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2088, in compile_args
    default_compilation_result, default_execution_result = try_march_flag(GCC_compiler.march_flags)
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1856, in try_march_flag
    flags=cflags, try_run=True)
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2188, in try_compile_tmp
    comp_args)
  File "C:\Users\cturn\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 1789, in _try_compile_tmp
    err += "\n" + str(e)
TypeError: can't concat bytes to str
```

Um, can't concat bytes to str? What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

The error you are experiencing appears to result from another sub-process utilizing the same resources as the script you are attempting to write. Although it sounds trivial, I would recommend making sure that you have admin privileges, or at least privileges to the desired resources, and/or restart your computer to kill the sub-process using that module. You could also look in the task manager and kill any/all other processes using python, but that might take longer.
(This may be the program using the "resource" try_march_3v6ffkv9.exe)

Comment: I restarted, and tried the same on an admin command prompt, but no difference. Not sure how to locate the programme using the process.